# How does “sendmail” send mails to any domain name?

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendmail, smtp

I noticed that one of our servers (running Ubuntu) can send mails to any domain (yahoo.com ,gmail.com) using simple "sendmail" command.

But I cannot figure out how to configure similar setup in a new server. I cannot see any files such as "/etc/mail/sendmail.cf" in the first server.

How does this work ? Does it use some other SMTP server to do actual mail delivery? Where can I find these settings?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably running postfix, not sendmail. The `sendmail` command is provided mainly for cross-compatibility.

You'll find the configuration files for postfix in `/etc/postfix` and [documentation at the Postfix homepage](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html).

Comment: It might be postfix...or rmail, or qmail, or nullmailer, or Exim....